# How to join points in Plot3D (rgl) in R

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I am trying to make a 3D plot and join the points according only to variable V1 but I am having the following result:

```
plot3d(Datos$V1,
       Datos$V2,
       Datos$V3,
       type="l",
       xlab="v1",ylab="v2",zlab="v3",
       group.by=Datos$V1,
       col = Datos$V1)
```

[image: 3D plot]

I am trying to remove the diagonal line but I can't seem to find the issue here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please provide us with some sample data or can you replicate the problem in a dataset that ships in an R package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `group.by` argument to `plot3d`.  You'll need to plot the groups separately.  For example,

```
plot3d(Datos$V1,
   Datos$V2,
   Datos$V3,
   type="n",   # Plot nothing, but set up the axes
   xlab="v1",ylab="v2",zlab="v3")
for (g in unique(Datos$V1)) 
   with(subset(Datos, V1 == g), 
     lines3d(V1, V2, V3, col = g))
```